# why tf.test.is_gpu_available() did not provide true or false,it got stuck?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04

After installing tensorflow gpu = 2.0.0 it got stuck after detecting gpu.
enviornment settings for this project is

1. ubuntu 18.04
2. cuda 10.0
3. cudnn  7.4.1
4. created a virtual enviornment
5. install tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0

While trying to check gpu with  tf.test.is_gpu_available().compliation got stucked it is shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEOzP.png)

Comment: If is the first time you launch Tensorflow? Try to wait 5 to 10 minutes if this is the case, Tensorflow needs to loads CUDA kernels the first time you execute a program.

Comment: 2020-04-16 16:08:46.499296: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (1): Tesla T4, Compute Capability 7.5 after getting this on console..it got stucked

Answer (score 0):

changed cudnn version to 7.6.2.Then it works well.